# Difference between $D$ and $E$ electric fields and how to prove their relation

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, dielectric

My original question was how I could get from

[$\Phi = \int \textbf{D} \cdot d\textbf{S}$] $\to$ [$\textbf{D} = \epsilon \textbf{E}$]

using Gauss' Law ($\iint_{A} \textbf{E} \cdot d\textbf{A} = \Phi_{E} = \frac{1}{\epsilon_{0}}\textbf{Q}$)

After attempting to figure this out myself, I came across two $\textit{seemingly}$ contradicting extracts from the Gauss' Law Wikipedia page - the apparent contradiction is what I believe to be the source of my confusion.

> Gauss' Law may be expressed as:
> $\Phi_{E} = \frac{\textbf{Q}}{\epsilon_{0}}$

and

> This formulation of Gauss' Law states the total charge form:
> $\Phi_{D} = \textbf{Q}_{free}$.

> where $Φ_{D}$ is the D-field flux through a surface S which encloses a volume V, and $Q_{free}$ is the free charge contained in V. The flux $Φ_{D}$ is defined analogously to the flux $Φ_{E}$ of the electric field E
> through S.

If someone could explain why, in the second equation, the free charge is not divided by a form of permittivity, I believe this would clarify a lot. I would also request a method of answering my original question!

Comment: I have been forced to answer my own question, so take it with a grain of salt as the sources are: the internet, textbooks and a lot of personal speculation/hypothesising. However, the answer, to me, is completely satisfactory and you may find it clears your head-pounding confusion.

Comment: You can read about it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZlNb.png), Griffiths EM (page:181-182) Edition 4 (don't have enough time to write an answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**D** field is ***defined*** as the **E** field multiplied by the permittivity + **P** field (keep reading, this will be explained). The **D** field is simply the amount of electric field that is felt/measured.
Its separation/distinction to the **E**-field, is for two reasons.

Firstly, some media '*allow*' or '*permit*' the electric field better than others. The *permittivity* of a medium is the constant that describes how much is '*let through*' said medium.
Secondly, due to the fact that materials are made out of charged particles. A dielectric material will respond to an electric field, **E**, by allowing the charges to move around, causing a net polarisation, **P**, of the material, which is its own 'electric' field. The device which measures the **D** field cannot differentiate how much of the field that it is measuring comes from the original source of the field, **E**, and how much has been negated from the *polarisation*, **P**.
However, we know that the measured **D**-field is a result of both of these effects, and is not an accurate representation of the **E**-field, instead it is:
**D** = amount of electric field *felt* = ε**E** + **P**

Before we go into it, it helps to know this;

$Q_{free} = Q_{enclosed} + Q_{dielectric}$

Now:
Gauss law states that the electric flux *caused* (as opposed to *measured*) by enclosed charge/s is proportional to said enclosed charge (thereby inadvertently NOT accounting for the effects of polarisation). It states that the constant of proportionality is 1/permittivity. Thus:

$$\Phi_{E} = \frac{Q}{\varepsilon}$$

Where Q is the enclosed charge.
Since **D** = ε**E** + **P** then by extension $\Phi_{D} = ε\Phi_{E} + \Phi_{P}$.
Thus,

$$\Phi_{E} = \frac{Q}{\varepsilon} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}(\Phi_{D} - \Phi_{P})$$

$$Q_{encl} = \Phi_{D} - \Phi_{P} = Q_{free} - Q_{dielectric}$$

Thus,
$\Phi_{D} = Q_{free}$.

This also makes intuitive sense, because when considering the **D** field flux, by definition;
**D** = ε**E** + **P** = displacement field = electric field *measured* (thereby accounting for the effects of polarisation or permittivity).
Since the **D** field accounts for permittivity and polarisation, we don’t need to include the permittivity in the flux equation; it is simply equal to the charge. However the charge measured here is the *free charge*, since free charge accounts for the additional charges formed in the dielectric.

> [Alternative explanation]:
> Under the
> assumption that there is no polarising effect (i.e. **P** = $0$), we can easily establish that
> $\textbf{D} = \varepsilon \textbf{E}$. Further, when there is no
> polarisation, there are no charges moving in the dielectric. Thus
> there is no charge stemming from the dielectric.
> By Gauss' Law,
> $\Phi_{E} = \frac{Q_{enc}}{\varepsilon}$. But as we said, now there is no
> dielectric charge so $Q_{enc} = Q_{free}$ --> $\Phi_{E} =
> > \frac{Q_{free}}{\varepsilon}$. And unlike the **E**-field, the
> **D**-field accounts for permittivity, so to find the **D**-field flux, we simply multiply by $\varepsilon$ giving us  $\Phi_{D} =
> > Q_{free}$.

This brings us to now needing to explain how the **D**-field - when **P** is $0$ and $\varepsilon$ is a scalar (as opposed to a tensor - which occurs in anisotropic materials) - is also the total measured flux density of the field.
Flux Density in derivative form is dFlux/dArea.
Since flux of an electric field (when **P** = $0$ and $\varepsilon$ is a scalar) is:
$$\Phi = \iint{D}.d\textbf{S} = \iint{\varepsilon E}.d\textbf{S} = Q_{encl}$$

Then,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d\Phi} }{\mathrm{d} \textbf{S}} = \textbf{D}$$

QED.

Comment: $\vec{D}$ is defined to be $\vec{D} = \epsilon_0 \vec{E} + \vec{P}$, with $\epsilon_0$ the vacuum permittivity. Maybe this is what you meant, but I couldn't quite be sure from your answer.